# Most efficient way to populate DropDownLists in a GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've got this code, and it works.  But it takes **forever**.  OK, maybe 40 seconds, but that's forever in an online application.

```
protected void DataGrid_Open_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    OracleConnection conn = GetConnection();
    try
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

            //**********************************************
            //*************  Auditor Names  ****************
            //**********************************************

            OracleCommand cmd4 = new OracleCommand();
            cmd4.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd4.CommandText = "CSTAPP_O.CST_AMR_AUDITORNAMES";
            cmd4.Connection = conn;

            cmd4.Parameters.Add("cursor_", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            var SearchAdapter4 = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd4);
            var ds4 = new DataTable();
            SearchAdapter4.Fill(ds4);

            DataView view = new DataView(ds4);
            DataTable distinctValues = new DataTable();
            distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "Auditor_Name", "AuditorID");

            DropDownList ddl = e.Row.FindControl("EI_Open_AuditorName") as DropDownList;

            ddl.DataSource = distinctValues;
            ddl.DataTextField = "Auditor_Name";
            ddl.DataValueField = "AuditorID";
            ddl.DataBind();
            ddl.SelectedValue = drv["Auditor_Name"].ToString();

            //**********************************************
            //*****************  Status  *******************
            //**********************************************

            OracleCommand cmd5 = new OracleCommand();
            cmd5.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd5.CommandText = "CSTAPP_O.CST_AMR_AUDITSTATUS";
            cmd5.Connection = conn;

            cmd5.Parameters.Add("cursor_", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            var SearchAdapter5 = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd5);
            var ds5 = new DataTable();
            SearchAdapter5.Fill(ds5);

            DataView view5 = new DataView(ds5);
            DataTable distinctValues5 = new DataTable();
            distinctValues5 = view5.ToTable(true, "StatusName", "StatusID");

            //                DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
            DropDownList ddl5 = e.Row.FindControl("EI_Open_AuditStatus") as DropDownList;

            ddl5.DataSource = distinctValues5;
            ddl5.DataTextField = "StatusName";
            ddl5.DataValueField = "StatusID";
            ddl5.DataBind();
            ddl5.SelectedValue = drv["Overall_Audit_Status"].ToString();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?  I can't believe that re-running a stored procedure for every record in a GridView is the best way to fill a DropDownList, and I've got 2 DropDownLists to fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `DataTable` to temporarily store data and a method to get the data into the DataTable and reuse it so you don't hit the database on every DataBound item.

```
DataTable dt;

protected void DataGrid_Open_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the current row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //check if the datatable already exists, if not get it from the LoadDataFromDB method
        if (dt == null)
        {
            dt = LoadDataFromDB();
        }

        DropDownList ddl = e.Row.FindControl("EI_Open_AuditorName") as DropDownList;

        ddl.DataSource = dt;
        ddl.DataTextField = "Auditor_Name";
        ddl.DataValueField = "AuditorID";
        ddl.DataBind();
    }
}

//method for loading data into a datatable and return it as such
public DataTable LoadDataFromDB()
{
    string query = "CSTAPP_O.CST_AMR_AUDITORNAMES";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
    {
        try
        {
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: I discovered this about 20 seconds before you posted it.  :o)  For all future visitors, this method worked like a champ.